# RSA Key generation fails on JCARD 2.2.2

Tags: java, eclipse, rsa, javacard, apdu

I'm beginner in JCard programming (2 days experience ...) and I'm trying to deploy an app on a CREF emulated card that generates an RSA KeyPair and sends the public key over to the host RMI Client application, somehow when I launch the init method from the client app I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
com.sun.javacard.impl.NativeMethods.getCurrentContext()B
at com.sun.javacard.impl.NativeMethods.getCurrentContext(Native Method)
at com.sun.javacard.impl.PrivAccess.getCurrentAppID(PrivAccess.java:454)
at javacard.framework.CardRuntimeException.<init>(CardRuntimeException.java:46)
at javacard.security.CryptoException.<init>(DashoA10*..:25)
at com.sun.javacard.javax.smartcard.rmiclient.CardObjectFactory.throwIt(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javacard.javax.smartcard.rmiclient.CardObjectFactory.throwException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javacard.javax.smartcard.rmiclient.CardObjectFactory.getObject(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javacard.rmiclientlib.JCRemoteRefImpl.parseAPDU(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javacard.rmiclientlib.JCRemoteRefImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sid2.CompteurImpl_Stub.initialiser(Unknown Source)
at sid2.ClientRmi.main(ClientRmi.java:36)
```

and here is the code from my JCard applet being called:

```
package sid2;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import javacard.framework.UserException;
import javacard.framework.service.CardRemoteObject;
import javacard.security.*;
import javacardx.crypto.Cipher;

public class CompteurImpl extends CardRemoteObject implements ICompteur {

    private byte compteur = 120;
    RSAPrivateKey rsa_PrivateKey;
    RSAPublicKey rsa_PublicKey;
    KeyPair rsa_KeyPair;
    Cipher cipherRSA;

    public void setPub(byte[] expo, byte[] mod) {
        rsa_PublicKey.setExponent(expo, (short) 0, (short) expo.length);
        rsa_PublicKey.setModulus(mod, (short) 0, (short) mod.length);
    }

    public byte[] getPub() {
        byte[] ret = null;
        rsa_PublicKey.getModulus(ret, (short) 0);
        rsa_PublicKey.getExponent(ret, (short) (ret.length + 1));

        return ret;
    }

    public void initialiser(byte v) throws RemoteException, UserException {
        rsa_KeyPair = new KeyPair(KeyPair.ALG_RSA, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_2048);
        rsa_KeyPair.genKeyPair();
        rsa_PublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) rsa_KeyPair.getPublic();
        rsa_PrivateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) rsa_KeyPair.getPrivate();

        compteur = v;
    }
}
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

PS: I already tried basic stuff and it worked just fine, like having a variable on a Jcard and incrementing it, getting it and setting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [JCDK User's Guide (for JC 2.2.2)](http://askra.de/software/jcdocs/kit-user-2.2.2/cJDKcrypto.html#pgfId-1000383) the CREF (C-language RE) implementation supports the following alogirthms:

> - 112-, 128-, 160-, 192-bit ECC
> - 512-bit RSA

Therefore, the line

```
rsa_KeyPair = new KeyPair(KeyPair.ALG_RSA, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_2048);
```

should throw a `CryptoException.NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM` when executed in CREF (as CREF does not support 2048-bit RSA).

Besides that error, that is likely the cause of the exception that you get, your code has at least one more issue:

```
byte[] ret = null;
rsa_PublicKey.getModulus(ret, (short) 0);
rsa_PublicKey.getExponent(ret, (short) (ret.length + 1));
```

Here you initialize the buffer `ret` to `null` but then you try to fill the modulus and exponent into the buffer. These two methods (`getModulus()` and `getExponent()`) don't create that buffer for you. Instead you need to create a buffer of appropriate size **first**:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[expected_length];  // Note that you certainly do not want to allocate that buffer within your getPub method!
```

And then you can fill the modulus and exponent into that buffer:

```
byte modLen = rsa_PublicKey.getModulus(buffer, (short) 0);
byte expLen = rsa_PublicKey.getExponent(buffer, (short) modLen);
```